# Concatenate elements in two lists with different length

Tags: python, list, concatenation

(I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I really couldn't find the right question. Perhaps I don't know the correct verb for this exercise?)

I have two lists:

```
prefix = ['A', 'B', 'C']
suffix = ['a', 'b']
```

And I want to get this:

```
output = ['A a', 'A b', 'B a', 'B b', 'C a', 'C b']
```

I am aware of the `zip` method, which stops at the shortest length among the lists joined:

```
output_wrong = [p+' '+s for p,s in zip(prefix,suffix)]
```

So what's the most Pythonic way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

While majority of the answers prefer `itertools.product`, I instead much prefer this:

```
output = [i + ' ' + j for i in prefix for j in suffix]
```

as it doesn't introduce a new package, however basic that package is (ok I don't know which way is faster and this might be a matter of personal preference).

Comment: I like how we got 4 answers of roughly the same thing within a minute. :D

Comment: @MateenUlhaq There are hundred similar questions out there, instead of answering this, we should direct OP to one of them, but you know SO.

Comment: @BcK In fairness to myself, I've already hit the rep cap for the day and just wanted to write a `itertools` answer. ;) ...Though closing as duplicate was probably the more accurate thing to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: As I said I probably didn't know the right word, in this case "cartesian product". Thank you guys for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use List Comprehension

```
prefix = ['A', 'B', 'C']
suffix = ['a', 'b']
result = [val+" "+val2 for val in prefix for val2 in suffix ]
print(result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['A a', 'A b', 'B a', 'B b', 'C a', 'C b']
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.product` and list comprehension,

```
>>> [i + ' ' + j for i, j in product(prefix, suffix)]
# ['A a', 'A b', 'B a', 'B b', 'C a', 'C b']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

prefix = ['A', 'B', 'C']
suffix = ['a', 'b']

print([f'{x} {y}' for x, y in itertools.product(prefix, suffix)])
# ['A a', 'A b', 'B a', 'B b', 'C a', 'C b']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a Cartesian product:

```
[p + ' ' + s for p, s in itertools.product(prefix, suffix)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `product`,

```
In [33]: from itertools import product

In [34]: map(lambda x:' '.join(x),product(prefix,suffix))
Out[34]: ['A a', 'A b', 'B a', 'B b', 'C a', 'C b']
```

Comment: Is there a reason you convert to list?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `list comprehension`:

```
prefix = ['A', 'B', 'C']
suffix = ['a', 'b']
output = [i+" "+j for i in prefix for j in suffix]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['A a', 'A b', 'B a', 'B b', 'C a', 'C b']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
map(' '.join, product(prefix, suffix))
# ['A a', 'A b', 'B a', 'B b', 'C a', 'C b']
```